# Use Multiple Azure Application Insights in one Flask app

Tags: python, azure, flask, azure-devops, azure-application-insights

Hi i have a flask application that Build as a docker image to serve as an api

this image is deployed to multiple environments (DEV/QA/PROD)

i want to use an applicationInsight for each environment

using a single application Insight works fine

here is a code snippet

```
app.config['APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY'] = APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY
appinsights = AppInsights(app)

@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
   appinsights.flush()
   return response
```

but to have multiple application i need to configure app.config with the key of the app insight

i thought of this solution which thourghs errors

here a snippet :

```
app = Flask(__name__)
def monitor(key):
    app.config['APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY'] = key
    appinsights = AppInsights(app)

@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
    appinsights.flush()
    return response

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    hostname = urlparse(request.base_url).hostname
    print(hostname)
   if hostname == "dev url":
      print('Dev')
      monitor('3ed57a90-********')
   if hostname == "prod url":
      print('prod')
      monitor('941caeca-********-******')
   return "hello"
```

this example contains the function monitor which reads the url and decide which app key to give so it can send metrics to the right place but apparently i can't do those processes after the request is sent (is there a way a config variable can be changed based on the url condition ?)

**error Message :**

> AssertionError: The setup method 'errorhandler' can no longer be called on the application. It has already handled its first request, any changes will not be applied consistently. Make sure all imports, decorators, functions, etc. needed to set up the application are done before running it.

[image]

i hope someone can guide me to a better solution

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Normally Application Insights SDK collect the telemetry data, and it has sent to Azure by batch. So, you have to keep a single application insights resource for an application. Use staging for use different application insights for same application.

When the request started for the service till to complete his response the Application insights has taking care of the specific service life cycle. The application while start to end it will track the information. So that **we can't use more than one Application Insights in single application**.

When Application starts the AI start collecting telemetry data when Application stops then the AI stops gathering telemetry information. We were using Flush to even though in between application stops to send information to AI.

I have tried what you have used. It confirms the same in the log
[image]
I have tried with single application insights I can be able to collect all telemetry information.
[image]